# Android - Dagger 2 injection differences

Tags: android, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am new to dagger 2. Need an understanding of the below.
Difference between

1. Extending DaggerApplication and overriding application injector and not injecting in every activity oncreate().

```
    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
    }
```

2. Not extending DaggerApplication class and injecting at the activity level.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // Make Dagger instantiate @Inject fields in LoginActivity
        (applicationContext as MyApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Difference Between those is: When You use DaggerApplication, it uses application context, the other way you can use activity context, some classes like Room database or shared preferences work with application context and activity context, but application context is enough, the other reason I think, dagger automatically add a class that has field with @Inject in dependency graph and it remove bridge between component and Module, I think it has own or create it by self and manage it.